# Enable mosaic acceleration in GeoServer 2.8.1

Tags: geoserver, jai

I want to enable mosaic in GeoServer 2.8.1 application.

Native JAI and Native JAI ImageIO are in true server status.
Installed  native JAI on Linux CentOS S7.

That is, I installed it.

But I still can't tick the Mosaic acceleration, which means it won't activate. What do I need to do?

Comment: It is probably hard to get help for that version (released 2015). The current GeoServer version is 2.21.

Comment: Please don't use a geoserver that old.